# PowerShell - Removing IP - Addresses with Remove-NetIPAddress

Tags: powershell, confirmation

.

Hey Guys,

one short question regarding the removing of IP Addresses with PowerShell.
I'm actually developing an automatic scripts, which also configures the
network settings. For this reason, I need it to remove the IP Address.
If I'm using the regular "Remove-NetIPAddress" command, i have to confirm
the removal and there is no "-Force" parameter.

Is there any other solution to remove the ip address without confirmation ?

Thanks a lot.

Best regards
NumeroUnoDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Remove-NetIPAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/remove-netipaddress) may not have a `-Force` parameter, but it does have a `-Confirm` switch.

Add that to your command as `-Confirm:$false`